# Concatenate express route parameter and file extension

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing

In my Express app I create snapshots whose details I store in MongoDB. The actual snapshot files are stored in the snapshots folder under their _id, eg `/snapshots/575fe038a84ca8e42f2372da.png`.

These snapshots can currently be loaded by a user by navigating to the folder and id, in their browser, i.e. `/snapshots/575fe038a84ca8e42f2372da`, which returns the image file. However I think to be more intuitive the url path should include the file extension; i.e. the user should have to put in `/snapshots/575fe038a84ca8e42f2372da` **`.PNG`** to get the file.

This is what I have currently:

```
router.get('/:shotID', function(req, res, next) {

    // Checks if shot exists in DB
    Shots.findOne({
        _id: req.params.shotID // More conditions might get put here, e.g. user restrictions
    }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(404).res.end();
            return;
        }
        var file = fs.createReadStream(`./snapshots/${req.params.shotID}.png`);

        file.pipe(res);
    });
});
```

How can I incorporate the user putting in the file extension in this path?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a [custom regular expression](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#custom-match-parameters) to match a named parameter, which can also contain a file extension:

```
router.get('/:shotID(?:([a-fA-F0-9]{24})\.png$)', ...);
```

For the URL path `/snapshots/575fe038a84ca8e42f2372da.png`, `req.params.shotID` will be `575fe038a84ca8e42f2372da`.

If you want to match both with and without `.png`, you can use this:

```
router.get('/:shotID(?:([a-f0-9]{24})(?:\.png)?$)', ...);
```